# Rails: One migration works when I run it individually, but not in a series with other migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I have a series of migrations for refactoring on the upcoming release. Some of the migrations are used to move columns around.

When I run the migrations all at once, the specific column in the following example is never copied to the new place.

```
  def up
    add_column :buy_topics, :price, :integer

    say_with_time 'Move price and value to buy/topics' do
      bar = ProgressBar.new(Buy::Topic.count)
      Buy::Topic.includes{topic}.find_each do |topic|
        topic.price = topic.topic.price
        topic.save
        bar.increment!
      end
    end

    remove_column :topics, :price
  end
```

Even though the values are not copied, the columns were still created and removed successfully though.

However if I run all the migration up to the the one prior to this (e.g. `rake db:migrate VERSION=XXXXXXXXn-1`), and then manually run this one particular migration (`rake db:migrate VERSION=XXXXXXXXn`), the values are copied across.

So in summary, if I run that migration individually it works, otherwise it will not work

What could be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
Buy::Topic.reset_column_information
```

For more information, look at "Using a model after changing its table" on [this page][http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html].

Comment: thanks, it works. I would thought without this, isolated single migration shouldn't work either. I guess there is something more that's going on under the table.